# SSHD/Hybrid drive flash size

Tags: hybrid-storage

I'm currently investigating changing my current laptop HDD for a hybrid or sold-state drive and for my price/performance requirements the current choice seems to be a 1TB Seagate Firecuda.  As far as I can tell the currently available models have 8GB of flash but this doesn't seem very much to me and I have found references that seem to say they used to use 32GB of flash:
https://blog.seagate.com/consumers/seagate-boosts-nand-flash-to-32gb-on-laptop-sshd/

(this seems to be a model that is no longer available on the Seagate site)

Is there a particular reason that hybrid drives seem to be fixed on 8GB flash and would there be a performance improvement if I was able to get one with 32GB (all else being equal)?

Edit:
My particular usage is; I'm running Windows 10 professional and develop distributed applications using .net core and c#.  My laptop is only a couple of years old but when I am building and deploying to the Service Fabric Cluster Manager locally things can really ground to a halt.

Comment: I expect its a matter of supply and demand - 8 gigs is probably more then adequate for your typical end user with lots of videos - while the people who would pay the extra for 32 gigs can now probably afford a dedicated SSD - or are using a 32 gig Optane chip as cache on a regular hard drive.

Comment: What OS are you using? Maybe `bcache` with a combination of HDD and SSD of your choice would fit better?

Comment: @davidgo - I have no idea what an Optane chip is but I shall investigate.

Comment: @EugenRieck I use Windows 10.

Comment: @jimbo-ish - Optane memory works like a giant cache.  Your first build would be slower than say an SSD the first time, but a second build would be faster than the first.  Compile times on an SSD + Optane would be extremely fast.

Comment: @Ramhound As far as I can tell, I cannot install an Optane module in my laptop so that's out.

Comment: You should improve the quality of this question.  You failed to mention you were using a laptop, if you had, you likely wouldn't have been given a suggestion you cannot use.  At the end of the day, it will be up to you to decide what you want to use.  A hybrid hdd isn't going to improve your compilation performance.

Comment: @Ramhound "my current laptop HDD" - first line! And the question wasn't asking what to use, it was asking about the 8GB vs 32GB flash and why it only seems to be 8GB available now.

Comment: We really cannot answer the reason why a product was discontinued and is no longer available.  Have you contacted Seagate with regards to this question?  Difficult to even tell when that article was submitted to the Seagate blog.   FireCuda drivers are more than 3 years without a single product refresh.  As for what is in the body of your question, I missed that information, despite reading your question at least 5 times before I made that suggestion